Assistance matching first and last names across tables in MS Access
I'm new to this forum, am a novice using Access/SQL and I appreciate any help people can give me. I'm using MS access and trying to use SQL to join 2 tables by customer name. Each table has columns of first and last name. However as many of you have probably experienced names are not unique and sometimes people use their formal name such as William, sometimes a nickname like Bill. I was wondering if I can somehow join the 2 existing tables with a 3rd table that contains of list of nicknames such as William/Bill, Mike/Michael etc. and have the query show results if either of the 2 names in the 3rd table match either name in the first 2 tables. There are no unique ID's for the customers. Hope I'm making sense. Thoughts on this, or has anyone come up with a better approach?
I've tried joining the 2 tables by last name and first name but get mixed results because of same last names of 2 different customers and different first names of the same customer.
This post from 9 years ago describes the same problem and lists a solution, but when I try it, it only returns rows where the Alias names are the same in Tables 1 and 2. I need it to return rows where the Alias names are the same, Official names are the same, or a mix of both.
Matching First and Last Name on two different tables

Will never get perfect results. There could be multiple William Smith with nickname Bill.

Yes, that is true, it will never get perfect results. But it will be a lot closer than the results I am seeing now.

Need a dataset of unique customer names. Are they unique in one of the tables? Would one table have all possible customers? Or are you saying a customer might be listed as William or Will or Bill in multiple records of one table? Need to assign an identifier to these customers. Determining whether William and Will and Bill are really the same customer will be a painstaking, tedious, case-by-case decision process.

Then validating record associations of two tables will be another painstaking, tedious, case-by-case process.

One table is the master roster so it contains all possible customers. The name in there might be William, but then other tables might have the same person listed as Bill. There is no unique identifier for these customers. Today I can only match those people by last name. If I could match by 2 possible first names, the odds of a match go up significantly.

Doesn't change my comments. Also, I don't see how throwing a 3rd table into the mix will help.
